# Attempting to create a shapefile with lines form a csv file of endpoints in python

Tags: python, csv, arcgis

I copied a python script off of the gis.stackexchange website.  The purpose is to covert a list of start and end points into a gis shapefile with lines that start and end at these same endpoints.  I have not used python before, so please be patient with me.

Here is the script:

```
import arcpy

outPath = r"S:\GIS data\Matthew Damage areas" #output path for the feature class
featureClass = "roadSegments.shp" #the name of your shapefile
spatialRef = arcpy.SpatialReference("WGS 1984") #the spatial reference you want; set it to whatever you want

arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(outPath, featureClass, "POLYLINE", " ", "DISABLED", "DISABLED", spatialRef) #sets up the shapefile we're using

arcpy.AddField_management(outPath + "\\" + featureClass, "segmentID", "SHORT", 15) #I assume that each segment has some sort of ID number that you might want to import into

roadArray = arcpy.Array() #this will hold the coordinates for each line segment until we write it to the shapefile.

roadFile = open(r"S:\GIS data\Matthew Damage areas\roadlines.csv") #the path to your road lines file
headerLine = roadFile.readline()
indexList = headerLine.split(",")

#now we need the index locations for the columns that contain the latitude and longitude points for the starting and ending points for each line segment.  I'm also assuming that each segment has some sort of ID value in your segment.  Change the value inside the parenthesis to reflect whatever you named your column for those values.

idValueIndex = indexList.index('segmentID')
fromLatValueIndex = indexList.index('fromLat')
fromLongValueIndex = indexList.index('fromLong')
toLatValueIndex = indexList.index('toLat')
toLongValueIndex = indexList.index('toLong')

roadCursor = arcpy.InsertCursor(outPath + "\\" + featureClass)

for fileLine in roadFile.readlines():
    readline = fileLine.split(",")
    idNumber = int(readline[idValueIndex])
    fromLat = float(readline[fromLatValueIndex])
    fromLong = float(readline[fromLongValueIndex])
    toLat = float(readline[toLatValueIndex])
    toLong = float(readline[toLongValueIndex])

    #now let's add the points and draw the lines
    fromVertex = arcpy.Point(fromLong, fromLat)
    roadArray.add(fromVertex)
    toVertex = arcpy.Point(toLong, toLat)
    roadArray.add(toVertex)

    roadCursor = arcpy.InsertCursor(outPath + "\\" + featureClass)
    feature = roadCursor.newRow()
    polyline = arcpy.Polyline(roadArray, spatialRef)
    feature.shape = polyline
    feature.setValue("segmentID", idNumber) #adds the segmentID in the attribute table

    roadCursor.insertRow(feature)
    roadArray.removeAll()

del roadCursor

print "Finished!"
print arcpy.GetMessages()
```

---

A shapefile is created, but the file does not contain data.

**Error:**

> Runtime error
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 23, in
>
> ValueError: 'toLong' is not in list

Comment: What is the first line of file `roadlines.csv`

Comment: Yep, you need to supply column names from the CSV - just the first line

Comment: Name,segmentID,Worksheet,fromLat,fromLong,toLat,toLong

Answer (score 0):

Presumming first line of `roadlines.csv` is `segmentID,fromLat,fromLong,toLat,toLong` you need remove final `\n` from the header :

```
headerLine = roadFile.readline().strip()
```

You can also simplify the code using [Python CSV module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)